# OpenLayers map controls failing to show up over HTTPS

Tags: https, openlayers

I have a OpenLayers map application running on a Django page. It uses a control panel to allow drawing on the map. We recently switched the site over to HTTPS, and now although the map loads, the controls don't show up and there are no Javascript errors. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: can you share the link or post some code to walk through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem with my configuration. The Apache server that was serving the CSS files wasn't configured correctly, so with no styling the controls simply failed to appear.